# Writing datetime.date with to_sql throws OperationalError

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I am using latest pandas 14.1 and using the to_sql method to write to a MS SQL Server 2008 v2 server.   Using SQLalchemy as engine.  The following dataframe with datetime objects works as expected.

```
#test DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10))
df1['A'] = 'Text'
df1['date_test'] = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)
```

code used to write to database:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://XXXXXXX')
df1.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

For business reasons the data in the database need to be date objects and not datetime.  If I use:

```
#test DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10))
df2['A'] = 'Text'
df2['date_test'] = datetime.date(2014,1,1)  # date not datetime
```

the to_sql method gives a very long error message:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (206, 'Operand type clash: datetime is incompatible 
with textDB-Lib error message 206, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error:
Check messages from the SQL Server.......
```

My first suspicion is that this might be a bug with the new created functionality in Pandas 14.1 if dates are used in method.  Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: starting from pandas 0.15, `to_sql` supports writing columns of `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8090, now in development version).

---

Support for `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` types is at the moment (0.14.1) not yet implemented (only for the `datetime64` type, and `datetime.datetime` will be converted to that), but it should be easy to add this (there is an issue for it: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6932).

The problem is that at the moment, `to_sql` creates a column of text type in the database for the `datetime.date` column (as is done for all columns of `object` dtype). For this reason you get the above error message.
A possible solution for now would be to create the database yourself, and then append the dataframe to it.