# Pandas to_datetime returns string object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using `pd.to_datetime(df_upload['date_field']).dt.date` to get just a date from `datetime object`. But result of this code is indeed `object type`. How do I get just a date from datetime object but with `data type` as `date` not `object`?

Answer (score 0):

It is date, check `type`:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(df_upload['date_field']).dt.date

print (out.iat[0])
print (type(out.iat[0]))
```

If need datetimes without times, it means times are `00:00:00`:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(df_upload['date_field']).dt.normalize()
out = pd.to_datetime(df_upload['date_field']).dt.floor('d')
```

Comment: I could not understand your first comment. Should output of  `pd.to_datetime(df_upload['date_field']).dt.date` be also date type, because in my case it is not?

Comment: `normalize()` and `floor` are still giving `time` alongwith the `date`.

Comment: @dan - no, type and dtype is different in pandas, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574) - similar is for dtype=object and type=date

Comment: But with `dt.date` I am getting `string` as output, any easier way I can change it to `date`  without `time`?

Comment: @dan - no, ther is no string, it is type='date', check `print (type(out.iat[0]))`

Comment: It is `date type`, correct,. But when I am uploading it to `SQL` table it is showing me string type. SQL is messing up the type here. thanks for your help.

Comment: @dan - second solution didnt work?

Comment: for second solution  when I connect to SQL, it is in date format. but drawback is it is also displaying time along with the given date value.

Comment: @dan - Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25166280/2901002) ?

Comment: yes, i think this exacltly is the isseu, thank you very muchh.